# How close the blocks in angular SSR web-site?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, mdbootstrap

When at first time I open my angular Server Side Render web-site i see that all my hidden blocks is opened. And that happens **only for first load**.

And yes, i use mdbootsrap collapse for toggle blocks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at my nav menu. Menu was created on MDBootstrap. After a long time search i found the problem in my  tags, the buttons prevented me for closing windows. I just was change them to  and all work up.

Answer (score 0):

My way of fixing this is to put a variable that tells when the page finish rendering.

1: create a variable:

```
public isLoading: boolean; // load the variable in the ngInit
```

Or

```
public isLoading = false; // already loaded variable
```

2: on each hidden block add the condition (*ngIf) to display:

```
<div class="hidden" *ngIf="isLoading === true">content</div>
```

3: add the ngAfterInit event that will set the variable to true

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.isLoading = true;
}
```

AfterInit info
https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: It didn't work to me. (( I found the decision